# Factorising a function in terms of its variables

Tags: functions

Let
$$
f =
\left\{
\begin{array}
2e^{-x-y}& \text{if } y > x > 0\\
0  &\text{otherwise},
\end{array}
\right.
$$
why can't this function be factorized as a function of $x$ times a function of $y$ for all pairs $(x,y)$ in the domain?

Im struggling to see why it can't just be factorised as $2e^{-x}e^{-y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is **not** a correct description of $f(x,y)$ at, for example, the point $(3,1)$. The formula $2\exp(-x)\exp(-y)$ predicts a non-zero result, while the actual density $f(3,1)$ is $0$.

**Remark:** Somewhat informally, if the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ truly factors, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But in this example, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. If we know that $X$ is bigger than $6$, then we know for sure that $Y$ cannot be less than $2$.